# How to add infoboxes to markers whit Kotlin where users can add text?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps-markers

I would like to add infoboxes to show above markers on click where users can write text and save it to firebase so other users can view it. How to do this with Kotlin?

Here is my marker code:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    // Do other setup activities here too, as described elsewhere in this tutorial.

    // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
    updateLocationUI()

    // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
    getDeviceLocation()







                //PRESSING WILL ADD MARKER
                mMap.setOnMapClickListener(GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener { point ->
                    val builder: AlertDialog.Builder
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert)
                    } else {
                        builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    }
                    val marker = MarkerOptions().position(point)


                    builder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to add a map location here?")


                                . setPositiveButton (android.R.string.yes, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                            mMap.addMarker(marker)
                                    //CUSTOM MARKER
                                    .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.pinetree_foreground))


                        })

                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, which ->
                            // do nothing
                        })
                                .show()

                        true


                    }
```